# Prove $R^1$ is a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Consider $R^1$ of all real-valued funcions on the unit interval.
For each $f \in R^1$, each finite subset $F$ of  $I$ and each positive $\delta$, let 
$$U(f,F,\delta)=\{g\in R^1 \mid \|g(x)-f(x)\| <\delta, \text{ for each }x \in  F\}.$$

Show that the sets $U(f,,F,\delta)$ form a neighbourhood base at $R^1$, making $R^1$ a topological space.

Could you help?

Comment: The natural thing to do is to write out the axioms for a neighborhood base and start checking them one by one. What happens when you do that? Do you get stuck in any particular place? Keep in mind, when writing a question on math.stackexhange, you should [avoid no clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: But what are the axioms? I confused with neighbourhood bases at a point x and global neighbourhoods.

Comment: Note the proper way to typeset $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ within MathJax, as in my edits to your question: $$ U(f,F,\delta)=\{g\in R^1 \mid \|g(x)-f(x)\| <\delta, \text{ for each } x \in  F\} $$